# c : How to generate random numbers without duplication in a two-dimensional array of languages

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, random

I want to put random numbers from 1 to 16 in a two-dimensional array without duplication.

I made a code that eliminates duplicates and puts new random numbers back into the array, but it keeps printing duplicate numbers.

Which part is wrong and why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
        int A[4][4];
        int i, j, k, l;
        int num;
        srand(time(NULL));
        int count;

        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
                for(j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {
                        //Re:
                        num = rand() % 16 + 1;
                        A[i][j] = num;

                        for(k = 0; k <= i; k++)
                        {
                                count = 0;

                                for(l = 0; l <= j; l++)
                                {
                                        if(A[k][l] == num)
                                        {
                                                if(k != i && l != j)
                                                {
                                                        j--;
                                                        count = 1;
                                                        break;
                                                //      goto Re;
                                                }
                                        }
                                }

                                if(count == 1)
                                        break;
                        }
                }
        }

        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
                for(j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {
                       printf("%3d", A[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
        }

}
```

I want to put random numbers from 1 to 16 in a two-dimensional array without duplication. I made a code that eliminates duplicates and puts new random numbers back into the array, but it keeps printing duplicate numbers.

Comment: You want a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: Put the numbers in the array in order, then swap them randomly.

Comment: It's an assignment, so I have to do it this way !!

Comment: A shuffling based solution is about as efficient as you can get with the requirement that each value occurs once and only once. What specific aspect of “this way” is required? If there is an explicit requirement from your instructor, you should add it verbatim into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put the numbers 1,…,16 into an array `tmp`.
2. Perform a [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) shuffle on `tmp`.
3. Iterate through `tmp` to copy its elements to `A` using the mapping `A[i/4][i%4] = tmp[i]`.

If you’re not convinced, try a few values of `i` by hand to assure yourself this works.

Comment: Thanks, but... may I know what is the problem with my code? I want to do it this way because it's an assignment

Comment: The answer to that is best found by *you* by stepping through your code with a debugger.